# Running Eclipse project with maven dependency to another project in same workspace?

Tags: eclipse, maven

In my workspace i have many maven projects with dependecies between them managed by maven.

When i try to navigate through the types it shows the maven installed artifact and not the actual class in the workspace residing in another project.

It will be of much help if eclipse autoresolves the maven dependency and point to the local project instead of installed artifact. Is there any we can force that.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated with the comment. Basically expect eclipse to autoresolve maven dependency to the local project in the workspace. This helps to navigate between types.